# Sin-and-guilt preaching...

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics, comments, moderation

Newbie (on Philosophy) here.

I’ve been reading questions to get a feel for how this site works.  I notice there’s at least one user who seems to take every opportunity to strongly preach a Christian sin-and-guilt message in comments and answers.  No discourse, just “you must repent your sin” and similar.

From reading the Help Center I would have thought this would not be tolerated.  Does this behavior merit flagging?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Proselytizing is definitely inappropriate — but my first thought is just applying SE guidelines. If a comment isn’t helpful in clarifying the question, then flag it for removal.

Just in general, content in Q+A should be as neutral point-of-view as possible. For comments this is less important. But bounds of reason apply and “be nice” ethos is in effect everywhere. Stay on topic in comments, try to address the question, don’t drag people into discussions. Feel free to bring the energy to chat, but this sort of thing isn’t really on-topic there either.

Comment: As I explore the site more I see many more borderline- (and some outright-) proselytizing comments from a couple of users, one in particular ... Most of the time they do not add anything substantive and seem to be ignored by other commenters.  Should I infer that this is accepted, or at least tolerated, and just ignore them?

Comment: @JimGarrison: Honestly, we cannot possibly read every thread and comment and evaluate its appropriateness. In the end, we do this as a hobby. If you find comments like these, feel free to flag them. I am increasingly fed with this kind of comment and addressing this (also in chat) did not change anything. I will happily delete them.

Comment: An actual link to [Be Nice.](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) would certainly help understand what users are expected to do and behave here :)

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking I apologize if my comment sounded like I was complaining.  I’m just trying to calibrate myself to the tenor of the site.  Thanks for your response, I will flag if the proselytizing is obvious and adds nothing, but give the benefit of the doubt otherwise.

Comment: @JimGarrison: Sorry if I came across annoyed or something, nothing of that kind. :) I actually like that it is you who addressed this issue since I crossed with persons because of this before. We need more users that act like you did here.

Answer (score 2):

Also a newbie, but I think that applying the SE policies is sufficient.  That being said, I believe that philosophy is a strong enough practice to tolerate answers such as "because God said so" within normal Socratic dialogue, without resorting to blocking and flagging and so forth.  "Because God said so" is a weak answer to "why", whether or not it is in bad taste.

Comment: I agree, which is why I plan to be careful and flag only really inappropriate comments. Thanks for your input.

Comment: These comments often do not contribute to the discussion. If that's the case, feel free to flag them. The point is not just to remove disruptive behaviour but also to streamline normal behaviour.

Comment: Would it be good to flag inappropriately materialistic comments as well?

Comment: @Keelan. Are you saying that we can start ignoring the site guidelines and start flagging everything we think is abnormal or not contributing to the discussion?

Comment: @PédeLeão: As long as the comment does not ask for clarification, constructively criticises the content, or adds additional context to the answer given, it is off-topic. In general, it is about improving the point of the answer as given. See the help center on comments. Giving your own opinion (or God's or whoever's) on the matter does not justify commenting. If you like this view to be represented, give an answer to the question. And as the votes show here: Faith is seen as belief, not Truth. Meta threads and votes are part of the "site guidelines".

Comment: @elliotsvensson: Inappropriate/off-topic comments should be flagged in any case, no matter the view they represent. If it is not asking for clarification or constituting constructive feedback, it should be considered as misplaced.

Comment: "Would it be good to flag inappropriately materialistic comments as well?" - yes.

Comment: And to be even clearer: this *also* applies to comments which are not proselytizing ("You must repent your sin") but just make claims from a particular reasonably debatable point of view ("We are created in God's image"; "There is no free will") without putting them in context ("In the Christian worldview, ..."; "According to current scholarship, ..."). These comments obscure the content and do not honestly contribute to its quality; they should be removed. The tricky part is the "reasonably" (though if people would just be forthcoming on this point by themselves there would be no issue).

Comment: @Keelan. So to clarify, I can flag everything that appears abnormal, unconstructive and anything that is reasonably debatable, especially faith doctrines such as atheism, materialism, empiricism etc (since they rely on dubious presuppositions). Well, that covers about everything said on this site!

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking. There is no site guideline that demands that every comment be justified, and it would be impossible to enforce anyway. How many people do you know that adequately justify their comments? It's sounds like you're just making things up. And it's also not realistic that you're trying to judge that my comments are based merely on opinion, and the your beliefs are somehow more superior than mine. All philosophical doctrines to some extent rely on belief, and I'm quite certain that my beliefs have a sounder foundation that yours. And for the record, I don't proselytize.

Comment: @PédeLeão you can flag it... does not mean it will be deleted. The "reasonably" is a judgment call (which is why flags are handled by democratically elected moderators). If you don't want your comment to become the victim of such a judgment call, be forthcoming with putting your comments into context.

Comment: @Keelan. What's the point of this discussion, when all you have to say is *just do it*? The problem is that moderators are trying to invent new standards that are arbitrary, impractical and perhaps even unjust, but when questioned for clarification, you can't provide a coherent justification for them. The reason is simple: there is no way to establish a double standard without making it clear that that's exactly what you're doing. Trying to cover up the fact leads to logical inconsistencies.

Comment: @PédeLeão there is no new/double standard. I have explained how I follow the existing guidelines as in the [help]. You take it into the absurd by claiming it includes everything on this site. "In a Christian worldview, man is created in the image of God" is not reasonably debatable, while without the first four words it is. Thus it is very well possible to follow the guidelines. What clarification do you need?

Comment: @PédeLeão: I do not care which belief you have or what it says. What I do care about is if you continue putting your belief forward against many posts that are widely related to faith without showing any effort of putting your comment into context with the point made by the post. It is the same with any other doctrine and the standard as it is written in the help center. Do not try to victimise yourself. I suggest simply not making comments à la "You are wrong because the bible says so." This is - most of the times (if not about the Bible) - besides the point and hence off-topic.

Comment: @Keelan. What does that have to do with site guidelines? And I have no idea what you mean concerning the context. The first four words make it debatable or not? How so? Actually, qualifying it with "In a Christian worldview" is actually misleading, because it suggest that the truth of the proposition is somehow dependent on the antecedent, which, of course, it is not. Therefore it would be irresponsible to talk like that.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking. This isn't about me. It's about your continued disregard for site guidelines and arbitrarily trying to justify yourself with newly invented rules.

Comment: @PédeLeão, at 1 Corinthians 9:20-22 Paul describes the process of making his message in a way that doesn't repulse his audience: "To the Jew I became like the Jews... To those not having the law I became like one not having the law...", which you can see played out in his speech at the Areopagus in Acts 17:16-34.  He very carefully identifies components of the Stoic and Epicurean worldview that provide entry for his message rather than beginning with a conclusion that wouldn't make sense to them.  Of course the approach would be totally different around Jews, for whom the Torah is what matters

Comment: @PédeLeão: These rules are in place all the time. The help center hasn't been edited in that regard. I consider the last two Meta questions more as an incentive for executing them more rigorously (and independent from you or your views) as it became a growing problem due to many Hot Network Post questions recently. If you have problems with that, feel free to open a question on Philosophy.Meta addressing it. Judgements of mods are always a potential matter of revision if community votes are accordingly.

Comment: To put this into context: Recently, there were four or even more automatic flags because of discussions of 20+ comments under a single post each day. We have to review these flags. It is work. Most of the times, it was due to users throwing in their own views on the subject matter (mostly strong opinions) with the discussion going off the rails afterwards. Nothing constructive for the post. This makes a pretty good incentive for preventing this kind of behaviour by more rigorous execution of the rules, as the cleanup afterwards includes judging the viability of every single comment.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking, if you're talking about "Why is faith seen as a sign..." then it's worth mentioning here on PSEMeta that this was the most popular post all month (judging by its highest placement on the "month" tab), PSE's opportunity to hook many new users and get lots of new people introduced to the practice and power of PHILOSOPHY who may never have known about it before... I want to encourage you that your work wasn't a mere waste of time and it was good not to delete the question.

Comment: @PédeLeão: Also, your comments have been flagged as not being relevant to the post or even outright offensive multiple times. It is not arbitrary behaviour by the mods following made up rules. We follow the official guidelines as laid down in the help center and other places (as Meta.SE). As hard as it may be for you to accept, under these guidelines your faith is considered opinion and not Truth. Everything else would be offensive towards people of different or no faith and against the Be Nice policy which asks for *mutual* respect.

Comment: @elliotsvensson: Thank you! Well, we volunteered for the position, so we have to deal with it ;) In this one we had to delete more answers than ever before, not to speak of comment threads. But there were others as well. And yes, I think it overall showed that we can balance the policies and plurality of views pretty well, also in explicitly religious context.

Comment: @PédeLeão I'm happy to clarify, but some of the questions you ask in your comment I already answered in my last comment. As for the last point about absolute truth / context, see Philip's forelast comment ("As hard as it may be for you to accept, ...").

Comment: @Keelan Although you refer to the help center, that place has multiple pages. I think you are referring to this: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic , the paragraph starting with "Please note..". Is this the part on which you base the policy under discussion here?

Comment: @Discretelizard there are really several relevant pages, which is why I didn't link anything specifically. Particularly relevant are [help/on-topic](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (indeed, "this is not a personal blog"), [help/promotion](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) (taking a religion to be similar to a product), [help/be-nice](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) (depending on the tone, the content we're talking about here can be considered belittling).

Comment: @Discretelizard The most important is probably [this page of the help center](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment), where it is stated what and when not to comment.

Comment: @Keelan Well, there are also several pages that aren't relevant and it can be confusing for some reading your statement where you refer to. But this is clear now, thanks.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking. In the past, when I challenged your decisions, you justified yourself with invented policies such as the *petitio principii* rule or saying that I wasn't arguing enough. And although it didn't involve removing any comment, you once claimed that I was "attacking" people, to which I replied that you giving my comments an overly negative reading. However, you never once claimed that any of my comments were removed for being offensive. Therefore, what a surprise it is that you're suddenly saying so now, especially since I have always been careful to abide by the guidelines.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking. Besides that, it's completely off-topic, because the question at hand has nothing to do with violations of the be-nice policy. I don't agree with your interpretation that topics of a different faith, in and of themselves, are cause for offense any more than topics of any other sort of philosophical view would be (Someone on this site once took offense about another person questioning the theory of evolution). Nor am I interested in arguing the point. I simply want to make it clear that I have not intentionally acted against the site guidelines.

Comment: @PédeLeão I do not know what the context is, but moderators have their biases too, and sometimes it is better to tone down rather than irk them.
I have seen a lot badly framed answers, and strange justifications from moderators.

Comment: @PédeLeão: I did not invent a policy, I pointed out that sentences like "God exists since he created you" are fallacious because of a *petitio principii*, since only *if* you assume God exists you can say He created you (or has shown us a path for how to find Him etc.), which in turn was meant to be an argument for His existence. Deletions were because of flags asking for moderator intervention, e.g. because of proselytising or "rude or abusive", four flags alone within the last 30 days. Be nice policy is on topic since intolerance, proselytising and dogmatic doctrine fall under this policy.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking. I'm quite certain that I was neither rude nor abusive.